# OpenGL ES 2.0 How to Draw Multiple VBOs with Different Shader Programs in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to hack the generic Xcode iOS OpenGL Game template to draw two vertex buffer objects and render them with different GLSL shaders.
I 'think' I'm rendering the two VBOs correctly? (Because I see them both when running both VBOs through the first shader program) However, my second shader does not appear to be rendering my second object at all.

Here is the vertex data for the two squares:

```
GLfloat gCubeVertexData[36] = 
{
    // Data layout for each line below is:
    // positionX, positionY, positionZ,     normalX, normalY, normalZ,

    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,          0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f

};

GLfloat fooVertexData[36] = 
{
    // Data layout for each line below is:
    // positionX, positionY, positionZ,     normalX, normalY, normalZ

    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,          0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

Here is where I am trying to generate two VBOs and bind them to the data. Not sure what the purpose of the 'glBindVertexArrayOES(0)' is at the end though?:

```
- (void)setupGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    [self loadShaders];

    //---- First Vertex Array Object --------
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray1);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer1);   

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer1);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gCubeVertexData), gCubeVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

    //----- Second Vertex Array Object ----------
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray2);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer2);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray2);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(fooVertexData), fooVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}
```

I'm using this update code to animate the model-view-projection matrixes:

```
- (void)update
{
    _rotation += self.timeSinceLastUpdate * 0.2f;

    float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);

    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f / aspect, 1.0f / aspect, -10.0f, 10.0f);
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(modelViewMatrix, GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(0.0 - _rotation));
    _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix2 = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(-0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    modelViewMatrix2 = GLKMatrix4Multiply(modelViewMatrix2, GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(_rotation));
    _modelViewProjectionMatrix2 = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix2);
}
```

When I call the '_program2' shader I don't see the second square:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer1);

    glUseProgram(_program);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    ///////// second object and shader program:
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer2);

    glUseProgram(_program2);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX2], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix2.m);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

}
```

I've basically tried duplicating the code for loading the first shader, to load the second. I suspect I may be doing something wrong here.. but I'm not sure what:

```
- (BOOL)loadShaders
{
    GLuint vertShader, fragShader, vertShader2, fragShader2;
    NSString *vertShaderPathname, *fragShaderPathname, *vertShaderPathname2, *fragShaderPathname2;

    // Create shader program.
    _program = glCreateProgram();


    // Create and compile vertex shader.
    vertShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"vsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&vertShader type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER file:vertShaderPathname]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Create and compile fragment shader.
    fragShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"fsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&fragShader type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER file:fragShaderPathname]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile fragment shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Attach vertex shader to program.
    glAttachShader(_program, vertShader);

    // Attach fragment shader to program.
    glAttachShader(_program, fragShader);

    // Bind attribute locations.
    // This needs to be done prior to linking.
    glBindAttribLocation(_program, ATTRIB_VERTEX, "position");

    // Link program.
    if (![self linkProgram:_program]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to link program: %d", _program);

        if (vertShader) {
            glDeleteShader(vertShader);
            vertShader = 0;
        }
        if (fragShader) {
            glDeleteShader(fragShader);
            fragShader = 0;
        }
        if (_program) {
            glDeleteProgram(_program);
            _program = 0;
        }

        return NO;
    }

    // Get uniform locations.
    uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");

    // Release vertex and fragment shaders.
    if (vertShader) {
        glDetachShader(_program, vertShader);
        glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    }
    if (fragShader) {
        glDetachShader(_program, fragShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    }


    ///////////////// the second shader:

    _program2 = glCreateProgram();

    vertShaderPathname2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader2" ofType:@"vsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&vertShader2 type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER file:vertShaderPathname2]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader2");
        return NO;
    }

    fragShaderPathname2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader2" ofType:@"fsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&fragShader2 type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER file:fragShaderPathname2]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile fragment shader2");
        return NO;
    }

        glAttachShader(_program2, vertShader2);
        glAttachShader(_program2, fragShader2);

        glBindAttribLocation(_program2, ATTRIB_VERTEX2, "position2");

    if (![self linkProgram:_program2]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to link program: %d", _program2);

        if (vertShader2) {
            glDeleteShader(vertShader2);
            vertShader2 = 0;
        }
        if (fragShader2) {
            glDeleteShader(fragShader2);
            fragShader2 = 0;
        }
        if (_program2) {
            glDeleteProgram(_program2);
            _program2 = 0;
        }

        return NO;
    }

        uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX2] = glGetUniformLocation(_program2, "modelViewProjectionMatrix2");
    if (vertShader2) {
        glDetachShader(_program2, vertShader2);
        glDeleteShader(vertShader2);
    }
    if (fragShader2) {
        glDetachShader(_program2, fragShader2);
        glDeleteShader(fragShader2);
    }    



    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type file:(NSString *)file
{
    GLint status;
    const GLchar *source;

    source = (GLchar *)[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] UTF8String];
    if (!source) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }

    *shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(*shader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(*shader);

#if defined(DEBUG)
    GLint logLength;
    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(*shader, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Shader compile log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }
#endif

    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        glDeleteShader(*shader);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)linkProgram:(GLuint)prog
{
    GLint status;
    glLinkProgram(prog);

#if defined(DEBUG)
    GLint logLength;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Program link log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }
#endif

    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)validateProgram:(GLuint)prog
{
    GLint logLength, status;

    glValidateProgram(prog);
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Program validate log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }

    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

My vert and fragment shaders are simple:

```
// vert shader1:
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}


// vert shader2:
attribute vec4 position2;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix2;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix2 * position2;
}


// frag shader(s):
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.12,0.32,0.54,1.0);
}
```

Comment: The OES suffix is not used in OpenGL ES 2.0

Comment: @MatisseVerDuyn That's misleading. Those functions aren't in the base OpenGL-ES 2 specification, so they are not defined by default, but they *are* offered as extensions (by supported devices.)

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to remember with OpenGL ES, is that you're using a procedural language within an OOP language.

You can only bind **one vertex array** to the vertex buffer at a time.

Binding two vertex arrays to the VBO, one after the other, and then applying transformations, will only transform the last vertex array attached to the VBO.

In your main loop, you have to iterate through your list of your vertex arrays. For each vertex array, bind it to the VBO, and then carry out any transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Unfortunately I'm still stuck. Can I not have two vertex buffer objects bound to separate vertex arrays, so that I can render them with different fragment shader programs?

Comment: First, you should really attempt to change your approach to only use one VBO. Secondly, you don't need different VBO's to run different shader programs. Compile two separate programs (a vertex and fragment shader *pair* are **required**), then call `glUseProgram( ... );` when you need to change between programs.

Comment: I see the two squares animating perfectly through the first shader program, but nothing through the second shader program. I get no error when the second shader program is compiled, and the second shader program takes pretty much exactly the same format as the first (just a different colour applied in the fragment program).

Answer (score 2):

The main problem was where I bound the 'position' attribute location for the second vertex shader. I had been using a 'separate' ATTRIB_VERTEX2 in my enum. Once I bound the 'position' attribute location to ATTRIB_VERTEX I was able to see the second VBO with the other shader program applied... Here is the code tidied up for anyone with the same problem/question:

```
// Uniform index.
enum
{
    UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX,
    UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX2,    
    NUM_UNIFORMS
};
GLint uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS];

// Attribute index.
enum
{
    ATTRIB_VERTEX,
    NUM_ATTRIBUTES
};

GLfloat square1Data[18] = 
{
    // Data layout for each line below is:
    // positionX, positionY, positionZ
    
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,  
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f
    
};

GLfloat square2Data[18] = 
{
    // Data layout for each line below is:
    // positionX, positionY, positionZ
    
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,  
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,  
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,  
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f
};

- (void)setupGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    
    [self loadShaders];
    
    //---- First Vertex Array Object --------
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray1);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer1);   
    
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray1);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer1);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(square1Data), square1Data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
//    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
//    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
    
    //----- Second Vertex Array Object ----------
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer2);
        
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(square2Data), square2Data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
//    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
//    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}

- (void)update
{
    _rotation += self.timeSinceLastUpdate * 0.2f;
    
    float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
    
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f / aspect, 1.0f / aspect, -10.0f, 10.0f);
            
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(modelViewMatrix, GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(0.0 - _rotation));
    _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
            
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix2 = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(-0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    modelViewMatrix2 = GLKMatrix4Multiply(modelViewMatrix2, GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(_rotation));
    _modelViewProjectionMatrix2 = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix2);
    
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray1);
        
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer1);
    glUseProgram(_program);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    
    ///////// second VBO and shader program:
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer2);
    glUseProgram(_program2);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX2], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix2.m);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6); 
}

- (BOOL)loadShaders
{
    GLuint vertShader, fragShader, vertShader2, fragShader2;
    NSString *vertShaderPathname, *fragShaderPathname, *vertShaderPathname2, *fragShaderPathname2;
    
    // Create shader program.
    _program = glCreateProgram();
    _program2 = glCreateProgram(); 

    
    // Create and compile vertex shader.
    vertShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"vsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&vertShader type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER file:vertShaderPathname]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }
    
    // Create and compile fragment shader.
    fragShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"fsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&fragShader type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER file:fragShaderPathname]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile fragment shader");
        return NO;
    }
    
    // Create and compile vertex shader.
    vertShaderPathname2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader2" ofType:@"vsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&vertShader2 type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER file:vertShaderPathname2]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }
    
    // Create and compile fragment shader.
    fragShaderPathname2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader2" ofType:@"fsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&fragShader2 type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER file:fragShaderPathname2]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile fragment shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Attach vertex shader to program.
    glAttachShader(_program, vertShader);
    glAttachShader(_program2, vertShader2);

    
    // Attach fragment shader to program.
    glAttachShader(_program, fragShader);
    glAttachShader(_program2, fragShader2);
    
    // Bind attribute locations.
    // This needs to be done prior to linking.
    glBindAttribLocation(_program, ATTRIB_VERTEX, "position");
    glBindAttribLocation(_program2, ATTRIB_VERTEX, "position");

    
    // Link program.
    if (![self linkProgram:_program]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to link program: %d", _program);
        
        if (vertShader) {
            glDeleteShader(vertShader);
            vertShader = 0;
        }
        if (fragShader) {
            glDeleteShader(fragShader);
            fragShader = 0;
        }
        if (_program) {
            glDeleteProgram(_program);
            _program = 0;
        }
        
        return NO;
    }
    if (![self linkProgram:_program2]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to link program: %d", _program2);
        
        if (vertShader2) {
            glDeleteShader(vertShader2);
            vertShader2 = 0;
        }
        if (fragShader2) {
            glDeleteShader(fragShader2);
            fragShader2 = 0;
        }
        if (_program2) {
            glDeleteProgram(_program2);
            _program2 = 0;
        }
        
        return NO;
    }    
    
    // Get uniform locations.
    uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
    uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX2] = glGetUniformLocation(_program2, "modelViewProjectionMatrix2");
    
    // Release vertex and fragment shaders.
    if (vertShader) {
        glDetachShader(_program, vertShader);
        glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    }
    if (fragShader) {
        glDetachShader(_program, fragShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    }
    
    if (vertShader2) {
        glDetachShader(_program2, vertShader2);
        glDeleteShader(vertShader2);
    }
    if (fragShader2) {
        glDetachShader(_program2, fragShader2);
        glDeleteShader(fragShader2);
    }    
    
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to use the same uniform in two diferent shaders just like the attribute ATTRIB_VERTEX?

Comment: @rraallvv I can't say for certain, as I don't know. But my guess is the attributes lose their context (i.e. go out of scope) between shader programs.